# Is it possible to write a Windows service using .NET that will trigger a function if any changes have occured in my local Access DB

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ms-access, windows-services

I have local Access database on my computer. The database is used by another application. I want to write a windows service using .net to send an sms when changes have occurred in the local Access database.

Answer (score 0):

there is no efficient way for the service to know if the database changed and know which are the changes, why not write a method in the other app to send the sms?

i'm assuming that the other application is developed by you, if that not the case, please give more context to your question so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately the other application is not written by me and the vendors stopped their operation. My Client need to keep the other application and need to send sms upon new receipts

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complex the application is and how often data changes, but You could use FileSystemWatcher to detect the moment when Access Data file has changed, then use some simple logic to check if table of interest is updated, for example look at row count in simplest case.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use Quartz.net to schedule a job that executes a job every *n* minutes and runs a query against the database to evaluate if records changed in specific table(s).

I have used TopShelf and Quartz.net to build similar solutions and it works reliably.  Here is a good tutorial to get you started: https://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/tag/topshelf/